# Terraform destroy my instances every apply

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have terraform project and every time I apply it's destroying my instances if exist and then creates a new one (even without any changes)

my terraform code:

```
    resource "aws_instance" "first_instance" {
  ami           = var.ami
  instance_type = var.ec2_type
  subnet_id = var.subnets[0]
  security_groups = [var.Web_app_sg_id]
  key_name = var.keyname

tags = {
    Name = var.tag_name
  }
}
```

terraform plan output (what terraform say need to be replaced)

```
# module.instances.aws_instance.first_instance must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_instance" "first_instance" {
      ~ arn                                  = "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:215364375712:instance/i-0891d9f95637fe077" -> (known after apply)
      - disable_api_termination              = false -> null
      - ebs_optimized                        = false -> null
      - hibernation                          = false -> null
      + host_id                              = (known after apply)
      ~ id                                   = "i-0891d9f95637fe077" -> (known after apply)
      - monitoring                           = false -> null
      + outpost_arn                          = (known after apply)
      + password_data                        = (known after apply)
      + placement_group                      = (known after apply)
      + public_dns                           = (known after apply)
      ~ security_groups                      = [ # forces replacement
          + "sg-04e4675374e29481d",
        ]
        tags                                 = {
            "Name" = "prod"
        }

      - credit_specification {
          - cpu_credits = "standard" -> null
        }

      + ebs_block_device {
          + delete_on_termination = (known after apply)
          + device_name           = (known after apply)
          + encrypted             = (known after apply)
          + iops                  = (known after apply)
          + kms_key_id            = (known after apply)
          + snapshot_id           = (known after apply)
          + tags                  = (known after apply)
          + throughput            = (known after apply)
          + volume_id             = (known after apply)
          + volume_size           = (known after apply)
          + volume_type           = (known after apply)
        }

  
      + ephemeral_block_device {
          + device_name  = (known after apply)
          + no_device    = (known after apply)
          + virtual_name = (known after apply)
        }

      
      + network_interface {
          + delete_on_termination = (known after apply)
          + device_index          = (known after apply)
          + network_interface_id  = (known after apply)
        }

    }
```

why does it happen? I didn't change anything at the values

Comment: Maybe you changed your instance in the AWS console?

Comment: nope, it happens when I do apply and then plan immediately

Comment: Usually you do plan, then apply. Why would you do it the other way around?

Comment: just to see if it will destroy my instance if I do apply and then after another apply its also destroying my instance

Comment: I think you have to provide complete example of what you do. The error says you are using some modules, but how do you use them is not shown.

Comment: Plan output states the instance needs to be recreated because it should be attached to a security group according to the config, and it is not. You would begin debugging by determining why that security group is not attaching to the instance originally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fix this problem by adding the ignore_changes block to the aws_instance resource:

```
lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      disable_api_termination,ebs_optimized,hibernation,security_groups,
      credit_specification,network_interface,ephemeral_block_device]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The security group ID you've provided is a VPC security ID rather than an EC2 Classic security ID, so you need to assign it to `vpc_security_group_ids` rather than `security_groups` in order to get correct behavior:

```
  vpc_security_group_ids = [var.Web_app_sg_id]
```

It's a quirk of the underlying EC2 API that it considers these two arguments to be somewhat equivalent, and so when you submit a VPC-style id in the classic argument the API accepts it but then when the AWS provider reads it back later it ends up in the `vpc_security_group_ids` argument instead, which the provider then misunderstands as "drift".

Populating the correct argument can therefore avoid that problem by making the configuration match how the API will interpret the settings, and thus avoid the misinterpretation as drift.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my environment and inspite of using lifecycle ifnore changes. just make one change i.e. replace security_groups with vpc_security_group_ids.